# Pandas append text into row

Tags: python, pandas

i have a single column , i trying to add "," into the row value but always

Getting error, "an int is required"

```
df = df['Cntr_Number'] + ','

print(df['Cntr_Number'].astype(str))
```

Comment: It would be better if u can include sample input in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just coerce the column to a `str` type:

```
df['Cntr_Number'] = df['Cntr_Number'].as_type('str') + ','
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df.loc[:,'Cntr_Number'] = df.Cntr_Number.apply(lambda x: str(x)+',')
```